# reading a os.popen(command) into a string

Tags: python, string, popen

I'm not to sure if my title is right.
What I'm doing is writing a python script to automate some of my code writing.
So I'm parsing through a .h file.
but I want to expand all macros before I start.
so I want to do a call to the shell to:

```
gcc -E myHeader.h
```

Which should out put the post preprocessed version of myHeader.h to stdout.
Now I want to read all that output straight into a string for further processing.
I've read that i can do this with popen, but I've never used pipe objects.

how do i do this?

Comment: Duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D+subprocess+output, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1180606/using-subprocess-popen-for-process-with-large-output  Even so, +1 for being clear and well-asked, and for "post preprocessed". :)

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The `os.popen` function just returns a file-like object. You can use it like so:

```
import os

process = os.popen('gcc -E myHeader.h')
preprocessed = process.read()
process.close()
```

As others have said, you should be using `subprocess.Popen`. It's designed to be a [safer version](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#security-considerations) of `os.popen`. The Python docs have a [section describing how to switch over](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#replacing-os-popen-os-popen2-os-popen3).

Comment: I don't think that the suggestion to replace `os.popen` by `subprocess.Popen` is still valid nowadays. I think this dates back from the transition from Python 2 to Python 3 when `popen`, `popen2`, `popen3` and `popen4` were deprecated. As of Dec. 2021, [the Python documentation for os.popen](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.popen) states that "This is implemented using subprocess.Popen; see that class’s documentation for more powerful ways to manage and communicate with subprocesses."

Answer (score 17):

```
import subprocess

p = subprocess.popen('gcc -E myHeader.h'.split(),
                     stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
preprocessed, _ = p.communicate()
```

String `preprocessed` now has the preprocessed source you require -- and you've used the "right" (modern) way to shell to a subprocess, rather than old not-so-liked-anymore `os.popen`.

Comment: Very nice example. Is there a way to separate the stdout and stderr streams?

Comment: Now `.split()` is one of the things that happen in a shell and make it unsafe to use. (Consider `subprocess.open(cmd.split())`, and the case that somebody passes in `'gcc "My Program.c"'` for `cmd`...)

Answer (score 5):

you should use `subprocess.Popen()` there are numerous examples on SO

[How to get output from subprocess.Popen()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1388753/how-to-get-output-from-subprocess-popen)

Comment: Please include an excerpt for the database to protect against link-rot.

Answer (score 2):

The *os.popen()* has been deprecated since Python 2.6. You should now use the *subprocess* module instead: http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen

```
import subprocess

command = "gcc -E myHeader.h"  # the shell command
process = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=None, shell=True)

#Launch the shell command:
output = process.communicate()

print output[0]
```

In the Popen constructor, if *shell* is *True*, you should pass the command as a string rather than as a sequence. Otherwise, just split the command into a list:

```
command = ["gcc", "-E", "myHeader.h"]  # the shell command
process = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=None)
```

If you need to read also the standard error, into the Popen initialization, you can set *stderr* to *subprocess.PIPE* or to *subprocess.STDOUT*:

```
import subprocess

command = "gcc -E myHeader.h"  # the shell command
process = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)

#Launch the shell command:
output, error = process.communicate()
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another approach which captures both regular output plus error output:

```
com_str = 'uname -a'
command = subprocess.Popen([com_str], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
(output, error) = command.communicate()
print output

Linux 3.11.0-20-generic  Fri May 2 21:32:55 UTC 2014 GNU/Linux
```

and

```
com_str = 'id'
command = subprocess.Popen([com_str], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
(output, error) = command.communicate()
print output

uid=1000(myname) gid=1000(myGID) groups=1000(mygrp),0(root)
```