# running shell command using python

Tags: python, shell

I'm trying to run a shell script in python and save the output to a variable.

This is my python script:

```
import os
os.system("sh ./temp.sh > outfile.txt") 
file = open("outfile.txt", "r") 
var = file.readLine() 
#I do more stuff using var
```

Right now this works. However is there a more efficient way to do this? It seems a little inefficient to output to a file and then read from the file again. My goal is to set var directly from the output of the os command. For example var = os.system(unix command). (I know this doesn't work).

Comment: You might want to look at the answer to this question

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4760215/running-shell-command-from-python-and-capturing-the-output

Comment: This answer to another SO post might be helpful. http://stackoverflow.com/a/2339494/434551.

Comment: Read about the [`subprocess`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) module, especially the [`Popen`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor) class.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `subprocess` module to store the output in a variable, thus making your script something like this :

```
import subprocess
var = subprocess.check_output(['sh', 'temp.sh']) //
```

The `subprocess` module basically allows you to execute shell commands which passed to it as an array of arguments so like to execute `ls -l` you need to pass it as ['ls', '-l'], similarly you can pass call to your script as above. You can read about `subprocess` [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#using-the-subprocess-module).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `subprocess` module

```
import subprocess
output = subprocess.check_output(//unix command here)
```