# how to make subprocess.Popen retrieve the entire stdout?

Tags: python, subprocess

The code is the following (on a python 2.7 prompt)

```
import subprocess as sp

a = sp.Popen(['bash', '-c', 'ssh [REDACTED] cat text.txt'],
             stdout=sp.PIPE, stderr=sp.PIPE)    
print(a.communicate()[0])
```

I would expect this program to print the entire "text.txt" file, however, it is missing the last few lines.

The file text.txt is in a remote server, which I assume is the gist of it. If I retrieve the file and then do subprocess.Popen locally, it works as expected.

Why does it happen and how can I fix it?

note: the result is the same if I use check_output

Comment: If you run that ssh command locally, do you get the full file, or is that also missing the last few lines?

Comment: I get the full file. The remote server might be doing something funny and not sending everything through stdout somehow?

Comment: what happens if you run: `print(repr(subprocess.check_output(shlex.split('ssh <host> "cat text.txt"'))))`?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation for `communicate`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate), the command shouldn't be used if the data size is very large.  Try something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1180632/2791611) and see if that solves your problem.

Comment: it didn't solve it, and the size of it shouldn't be massive (the txt itself is not massive at least)

Comment: What happens if you store `text.txt` locally and then replace your `ssh` command with just `cat text.txt`?

Comment: @amiller27: [update your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/37240933/edit) and specify an approximate size of the file (1K, 100K, 1M, 10M, 1G, etc)?