# Python standard output StdOut to file is limited to 65 kB

Tags: python, subprocess, stdout, popen

I have a task of batch image processing through ExifTool and output to StdOut. When I use the classic program launch, the task is executed and StdOut contains a full image.
However, ExifTool has a faster mode for working in batch. When it runs in standby mode only once, and then accepts arguments via StdIn. This is where the problem begins.
As far as I understand, it only accepts arguments in universal_newlines=True mode. But in this case, output = proc.stdout.read() no longer works.

This StdOut contains a full image.

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(['exiftool', '-jpgfromraw', '-b', '-o -', '/Volumes/RAM Disk/0204.NEF'],
                          stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
output = proc.stdout.read()

with open('/Volumes/RAM Disk/01.jpg', 'wb') as out_file:
    out_file.write(output)
```

I was able to output the file like this, but max 65KB only:

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(
     ['exiftool', "-stay_open", "True", "-@", "-"],
     universal_newlines=True,
     stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

exiftool_args_extract_preview = f"-b\n-jpgfromraw\n-0-\n/Volumes/RAM Disk/0204.NEF\n"
proc.stdin.write(str.join("\n", (exiftool_args_extract_preview, "-execute\n")))

proc.stdin.flush()
output = ""
fd = proc.stdout.fileno()
output = os.read(fd, 65535)

with open('/Volumes/RAM Disk/01.jpg', 'wb') as out_file:
    out_file.write(output)
```

But it doesn’t output more than 65 KB... I don’t know how I can get the whole image.
I tried entering different numbers into the argument for os.read but the file always turns out to be either less than or no more than 65 KB.

Python 3.12

Comment: I assume you are going to do something more with the image? Because as written, you could just have exiftool output it directly to the `01.jpg`. Related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1180606/using-subprocess-popen-for-process-with-large-output

Comment: @JPA I expect to do some more processing, but I want to avoid writing intermediate results to disk.

Comment: With a RAM disk, that may be the more performant option. But just keep reading from the stream if you want to get more than the first 64 kB.

Comment: @JPA RAM disk: I would try writing to RAM (instead of stdout), but so that the program thinks it is writing the file to the hard drive. Is this what you meant? Can you give at least a hint on how to implement this?

Comment: Based on your paths, you are already working on a RAM disk.